# How to make a query with 3 joins in Yii2

Tags: php, sql, activerecord, yii2

all! I hope anyone knows how to find a solution for this problem. I've 3 tables for joining, but when I try to make joining via join method I cannot get related tables and where statement isn't working at all. So, I've a method

```
public static function get_by_abc($letter = null,
                                  $object = false) {

    $result = self::find()
                    ->join('INNER JOIN', 'geo_place', 'geo_place.city_id = geo_city.id')
                    ->join('INNER JOIN', 'bus_station', 'geo_place.place_id = bus_station.geo_place_id')
                    ->join('INNER JOIN', 'bus_company', 'bus_station.company_id = bus_company.id')
                    //->innerJoinWith('companies')
                    ->where(['bus_company.active' => 1])
                    ->andWhere(['like', 'geo_city.name', $letter.'%', false]);

    if(!$object) $result->asArray();

    return $result->all(); //->createCommand()->rawSql

}
```

Next, I was trying to make a solution via with yii2 method, however It wasn't working too :( I looks like

```
    public function getCompanies() {
    return $this->hasMany(BusCompany::className(), ['id' => 'company_id'])
    ->viaTable('bus_station', ['geo_place_id' => 'place_id'])
    ->viaTable('geo_place', ['city_id' => 'id']);
}
```

But in this case I have join with geo_place and bus_company, but not with bus_station.

So a structure of the tables looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to define relation tree like this:

```
public function getBusStation()
{
   return $this->hasOne(BusStation::className(), [...]);
}
public function getBusCompanies()
{
   return $this->hasMany(BusCompany::className(), ['id' => 'company_id'])->via('busStation'); // it will use your relation `getBusStation()` to join bus companies by this relation
}
```

Its easy to maintain and understand, hope it will help You.